# @Html.CheckBoxFor wont change the value of a variable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Here's the situation, i have a ClassA which contains a list of ClassB objects. ClassB has 3 variables, an int, a bool, and a string. I'm trying to change the bool variable when i list it ( using foreach inside a View). The listing part runs smoothly(i get to choose which checkbox to check), but values of checkboxes that user selects dont get remembered.

This is a view model :

```
@model ClassA
...

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Registration", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
       ...
      <p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName) </p>
      <p>Adress:             @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Adress)</p> 

      foreach (ClassB check in Model.ClassBlist)
      {

      <p>@check.Name:@Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>check.attributeChecked,check.itemID)</p> 

        }
   ``...
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.ClassBlist.Count; i++)
{
    <p>
       @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ClassBlist[i].Name)
       :
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(
           x => x.ClassBlist[i].attributeChecked, 
           Model.ClassBlist[i].itemID
       )
    </p> 
}
```

This time the CheckBoxFor helper will generate correct name for the corresponding input field so that the default model binder is able to properly bind it when you submit the form.

Comment: still wont work. all other items in classA are returned nicely to controller when i press the submit button, but the list is still empty . any other suggestions ?

Comment: Does your POST controller action take the same model as the one used in your view? Or does it take the list directly as parameter?

Comment: Yes, its the same model. I solved the problem now(made by my mistake) and it works perfect thanks to code you wrote above. but i have another question for you : Model.ClassBlist[i].itemID doesnt return its value (nor does @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ClassBlist[i].Name)), instead i had to use @hidden element to return their values, but i made it work. My question is why it wont work the way you proposed, because it should !

Comment: You need to use a hidden field if you want the value to be sent to the server. The Html.DisplayFor helper only displays a simple string in the HTML which never reaches your server when the form is submitted.

Comment: but, what about @Html.CheckBoxFor(
      x => x.ClassBlist[i].attributeChecked, 
           Model.ClassBlist[i].itemID
       ), shouldn't it return the value of itemID ? thanks for your patience :)

Comment: No, of course not. The only thing that the checkbox will send is the `attributeChecked` property.